# Transpose a matrix giving me error when column>row

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

i want to transpose matrix
the code works when column=row and when column>row
but when row > column i get wrong answers

all of the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


 int main() {int row,column,tmp;
    scanf("%d",&row);
    scanf("%d",&column);
 int *image=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*row*column);
     int *target=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*row*column);
     for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<column;j++){
             scanf("%d",&tmp);
             image[i*column+j]=target[i*column+j]=tmp;
         }
     }
   transpose(row,column,target,image);
for (int i = 0; i< m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d\t", target[i*column+j]);
    printf("\n");
}}
void transpose(int row, int column,int* target,int* image) {
    
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                target[j * column + i] = image[i * column + j];
            }
        }
    
    }
```

my matrix in the image and i want to the transpose in the target .

```
input : 
1   2
3   4
5   6

output(what i get from my code) :
1   3   5   
5   4   6   
output (what should i get ) :

1   3   5
2   4   6

input work : 
1 2 3 
4 5 6
output : 
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: Please show the code where you call your `transpose`-function;

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. I suggest to add a `main` function that provides the necessary variables, fills the array with hard-coded input values, calls `transpose` and prints the result.

Comment: Please note that `target` and `image` have different `column` values (one should be `row`, if you are transposing), in the formula you are using to calculate the indeces.

Comment: `image` and `target` have different width but you are referring to them with the same `column`.

Comment: image and target have the same width (m*n)

Comment: Did you try compiling with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and debugging your executable with [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) ?

Answer (score 1):

As @Bob_ suggests, you are mis-calculating the offset into your target array.

Your source image has `column` columns and `row` rows; but the transposed image as `row` columns and `column` rows! (By the way - that's a poor choice of identifiers; consider `num_columns` and `num_rows` as parameters to the transpose function). So I believe you need to have:

```
target[j * row + i] = image[i * column + j];
```

in your inner loop.

Comment: i tried  { target[j * row + i] = image[i * column + j]; } , and still not working the output {1 3 5 
5 2 4 }

Comment: @jadegbaria: If you had provided a complete program, I might have been able to help.

Comment: i edited and added full program

Comment: @jadegbaria: No, you haven't.

Comment: what part did u need?

Comment: @jadegbaria: A complete program which compiles and runs.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what you are doing, I recommend you to print index value computed in you algorithm.
The problem is that `i` can be greater than `column` (same thing with `j` and `row`). You have to use `%` to improve your code.

Comment: i tried still giving me wrong